# Deserialize complex json in C#

Tags: json, deserialization

I have this json and need to parse the nested details. using **Newtonsoft.Json** for Deserializing but cant really parse this complex json.

```
{
"name": "John",
"email": "john@gmail.com",
"data": [
    {
        "company_name": "instagram",
        "company_email": "abc@email.com",
        "org": {
            "org_name": "john-insta",
            "org_dob": "1/1/1990",
            }
    },

   {
        "company_name": "google",
        "company_email": "abc1@email.com",
        "org": {
            "org_name": "john-google",
            "org_dob": "1/1/1990",
            }
    },
]
```

The number of entries in "data" may actually be varying dynamically, how do I parse the entries for *company_name*, *company_email*, *org_name,org_dob*.

Comment: "data" seem to be a simple array, show your code for parse it please.

Comment: you could use this: http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem you are having? This seems fairly simple JSON array. Setup your classes like this.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public List<DataClass> data { get; set; }
}

public class DataClass
{
    public string company_name { get; set; }
    public string company_email { get; set; }
    public Org org { get; set; }
    //Any other and all possible properties...
}

public class Org
{
    public string org_name { get; set; }
    public string org_dob { get; set; }
}
```

Then it can be parsed using Newtonsoft or similar using.

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

This method also has an overload where you can pass settings to ignore nulls.

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json, 
                new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

Comment: entries in data are changing dynamically..this is where I am having trouble

Comment: If some items in "data" have different properties, insert all properties in your Data Class, even they would be null.

Comment: What @fsbflavio said. The DeserializeObject method has an overload where you can pass settings, and set to ignore nulls. I will update answer.